# Knitr keeps executing and cannot be cancelled after error

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

Every time I run into an error while knitting a script that stops execution, RStudio behaves in a weird way: In the R markdown tab it reads in red that the execution is stopped but in the R markdown tab I see the continuing progress circle still moving, suggesting that knitting is still ongoing. Also on the right hand I see that "stop" sign but clicking on it also does not stop executing. I can still write text in the script but I can no longer execute the script and can also not kick off a new knitting attempt.

[image]

The only way of going back to normal is top close Rstudio and re-start it. That means, everytime I run into any kind of error while knitting I have to restart Rstudio. This does not occur on my private PC with the same scripts.
I have installed a new version of Rstudio (the new 1.4 Preview) and I have re-installed R Markdown. Do you have any tips?

edit:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmarkdown_2.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13  knitr_1.30       magrittr_2.0.1   tidyselect_1.1.0
 [5] R6_2.5.0         rlang_0.4.9      dplyr_1.0.2      tools_4.0.3     
 [9] xfun_0.19        pacman_0.5.1     htmltools_0.5.0  ellipsis_0.3.1  
[13] yaml_2.2.1       digest_0.6.27    tibble_3.0.4     lifecycle_0.2.0 
[17] crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.4      tidyr_1.1.2      vctrs_0.3.5     
[21] clisymbols_1.2.0 glue_1.4.2       evaluate_0.14    compiler_4.0.3  
[25] pillar_1.4.7     generics_0.1.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidylog_1.0.2
```

Comment: Are you working with large data files? You might be running out of memory.Try to clean your work environment and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.No, I have the problem even when executing the standard Rstudio sample that does not use any data what so ever..

Comment: Have you tried to use ```{r error=TRUE} ? In this case the document should be knitted regardless of errors, and the error description will be in the document. Hopefully it will print out the error that  is causing your problem